# what are the different ways I can encrypt stored procedure in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, encryption, database-administration

I am using `SQL Server 2012`. I wrote a stored procedure with encryption function i.e., "With Encryption". But I can "Decrypt" this stored proc using third party tools.

I need a way to encrypt a stored procedure in such a way that its almost impossible to decrypt it back.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt it?

Comment: Have you tried by granting or revoking View Definition rights.

Comment: I dont want to expose my business logic. Even to DBA.

Comment: @Naresh How do you expect the SQL Server to run something it can't read?

Answer (score 0):

Youc an use `

> WITH ENCRYPTION

to encrypt the text of the Stored Procedure.

Example :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #EncryptSP WITH ENCRYPTION AS

GO
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate your answer. But, as I already mentioned in my question, I've used "With Encryption" function. But the thing is, I can Decrypt the sproc which is encrypted with that function. I am in search of a way to encrypt sproc which is not that easy to decrypt.

Comment: you should than follow some different type of encryption .. mostly i prefer certificate ones check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) is three different level of encryptions that you can use to protect your database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a synonym for the stored procedure. In this way you can hide the actual name of stored procedure. Also try playing with grant permission after creating the synonym.